# How to distribute my apps to My friends?

Tags: android

I have developed an application for android, and now I want to share it with friends who live aboard.
How can I send app to him, I have export this app and uploaded it to my server.
Can anyone please tell me what the procedure to install this app on my friends phone?

Answer (score 2):

Simply download the .apk file from your server or send them an apk file and open/install it in Android phone by using **`adb install`** command from the console.

But before that, your friend must have to ensure that **Unknown sources** has been checked, Unknown sources can be found here: **settings->applications**.

Comment: They'll also probably need to have allowed Unknown Sources in the Application settings.

Comment: To run command his friends needs to install android sdk then after he is able to install apk using the adb command

Comment: How he download the application from phone?

Comment: you have to send apk to him in mail.

Answer (score 2):

Steps To Install Apk In your Mobile.

```
1) Go to Setting -> Application -> Tick Unknown Source
2) Copy Apk in sdcard.
3) Now Install Astro File Manager from Market.
4) After Installing it Open Astro and Go to your apk.
5) Click on your Apk.
6) It will ask Two Options . Click on Open App Manager
7) It will open a page from where you can install Apk to your phone
```

Comment: is Astro free software? can i download it from my emulator?

Comment: if you have an apk then you can send him in mail

Comment: then how can he install that on his phone?

Comment: if you think this is right answer then plase tick as it right

Answer (score 1):

Send him the link to your .apk.

But he must enable Non Market Apps he can find it in the settings under
Settings->Applications and enable Unknown Sources

Answer (score 1):

Check out installfish.com. It makes the whole process of Android and IOS app distribution extremely simple.

In a nutshell you sign up for an account, upload your app, choose a unique url then give that url to anyone you want to install the app. There is a whole bunch of other stuff you can do with the platform over and above this as well.

It is well worth checking out.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't just want to distribute the app to your friend but reach a wider audience, you can create a developer account for the android market. Information about how to do this can be found here: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html

This will cost you a one time fee of 25$. But it will allow you to distribute the app all over the world. Your friend will then be able to just download it.

Otherwise send him the download link and make him check "Unknown Sources" under Settings -> Applications

Comment: Thanks, i just need to give him only for now.....i will create account later....my question is how my friend install the apps from link.. i have no knowledge about real android phone yet :) i am working with emulator.