# problem installing apk file

Tags: android, android-install-apk, file-location

hey guys,i created a google map based application in android using eclipse..i created an apk file of the application and transferred the apk file to my google nexus one phone...but after successfully transferring the file i was not able  to locate the apk file on my sd card...guys plzzz help me out!!!

Comment: HI,Chetan Please [Follow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897550/how-to-distributed-my-apps-to-my-friend/5897718#5897718) my answer . Here i mentioned some steps to install apk on device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a programming question.

Download a file manager (e.g. ASTRO File Manager) to browse your SD card to find the apk file. Make sure that you enable the installation of non-Market applications through Settings -> Programs.

Or do as Moystard said to do it straight from Eclipse (smarter). Debugging mode is under Settings -> Programs -> Development, I think.

The driver: http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html

Answer (score 0):

Normally you just have to connect your Nexus (install the Nexus drivers first), enable the debugging mode, and install/launch the application right from Eclipse.